# MVC2 HttpPost Not Receiving Data Members

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a simple model class (UserAddress) that is not being passed properly to the HttpPost function. The data always has null values for all the member data.

```
public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public string Address1;
    public string Address2;
}

public class UserAddress
{
    public User User;
    public Address Address;

    public UserAddress()
    {
        User = new User();
        Address = new Address();
    }
}
```

And a simple view:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.User.Name) %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.User.Name) %>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.User.Name) %>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Address.Address1)%>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Address.Address1)%>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Address.Address1)%>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Address.Address2)%>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Address.Address2)%>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Address.Address2)%>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And here's the code:

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        UserAddress userAddress = new UserAddress();

        return View(userAddress);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(UserAddress userAddress)
    {
        return View(userAddress);
    }
```

All the member variables are null; such as userAddress.User.Name.

Comment: I hope you have specified model binding in your view like this System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<UserAddress>.

Comment: True, but if he didn't, his code would give a runtime error, not a null http post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing that stands out for me is that you are attempting to bind public members, not properties.

Perhaps try refactoring your classes to use properties and try that.

```
public class Address
{
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
}

public class UserAddress
{
    public User User { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }

    public UserAddress()
    {
        User = new User();
        Address = new Address();
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried that but the inner classes. But hadn't tried that for the UserAddress class. Duhhhh.

Comment: This was my problem. I kiss you!